# Saving data into data frame from Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, saving-data

I am trying to save the data from the Shiny app to the data frame. Currently I do it locally with the hope that I can do it remotely later. However I have troubles even saving it locally. It does not save and then periodically RStudio asks me to terminate my R session after I quit my app.  I got the code to work a couple of days ago, but now it is stuck.

I was following [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) with slight modifications:

- I don't need to load the data frame in the app, so I removed `output$responses`. But even if I add it back, the code still doesn't work.
- I would like to load up the last entry if that exists, so I added `observeEvent(input$load...`.

I do not have any errors. So I'm not sure what is going on.

My code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")

default_name <- ""
default_used <- FALSE
default_years <- 2


saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <- data
  }
}



ui = fluidPage(
    #DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", default_name),
    checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", default_used),
    sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R",
                0, 25, default_years, ticks = FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit"), 
    actionButton("load", "Load")
  )
  
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })
    
    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$load, {
      if (exists("responses")){
        updateTextInput(session, "name", value = responses[nrow(responses), "name"])
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = responses[nrow(responses) ,"used_shiny"])
        updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = responses[nrow(responses) ,"r_num_years"])
      }
    })     
  }


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried:

- creating the `responses` data.frame manually
- restarting RStudio in case of a glitch
  It didn't help.

I expect the code to save the input data into data.frame `responses`.

Comment: I read the link and I think you have the code of the section "basic shiny app WITHOUT data storage". In the function "saveData", you do not save anything because the object "responses" only exists in that function. If you want it persistent, you should write the data to a file, or (not a good practice, just use it for debugging) save it as a global variable with `responses <<- data` and `responses <<- rbind(responses, data)`

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot about global variable syntax.